# deletion while polling with null value in field

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-integration

Code :

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
        query="SELECT USER_ID,BOOK_ID FROM BOOK WHERE ROWNUM &lt;= 11"
        channel="index-back-data" data-source="dataSource"
        max-rows-per-poll="10"
        update=" ? "
        row-mapper="DataRowMapper">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10000" />
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

problem :

while polling over the BOOK table i might get bookid as null so how to delete it using the update property?

can we use conditional delete  in update as 

`:bookId != null ? 'DELETE FROM BOOK WHERE USER_ID = :userId AND BOOK_ID = :bookId : DELETE FROM BOOK WHERE USER_ID = :userId AND BOOK_ID IS NULL`

any help will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you may have a data integrity issue if you're allowing rows to exist with a null primary key in your book table. That's a bit editorial, so what about:

```
update="DELETE FROM BOOK WHERE (USER_ID = :userId AND BOOK_ID = :bookId) OR (USER_ID = :userId AND BOOK_ID is null)"
```